# why access_token change to accessToken in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

my pojo
public class VerifyLoginRespDto {

```
private String access_token;//NOSONAR
private String refresh_token;//NOSONAR
private String edit_by_user;//NOSONAR
private String scope;//NOSONAR
private String token_type;//NOSONAR
private String expires_in;//NOSONAR
```

}

the controller file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
VerifyLoginRespDto verifyLogin(@RequestBody @Valid VerifyLoginDto verifyLogin) {
    // some code
}
```

but my response have camel key like this

```
{
    "scope": "basic,",
    "refreshToken": "c2a4f22b-6446-49ad-8cc9-ef1a844d6cbb",
    "tokenType": "bearer",
    "expiresIn": "2591892",
    "accessToken": "54b3f27b-ad5c-4d7b-ae5d-07f56f5f2f42",
    "editByUser": "0"
}
```

why the key access_token change to accessToken in Spring boot?

Comment: Beause I user Jackson , It will output json by the getter method .And my method nama is getAccessToken, so When I use the gson , the wrong goes away。

Answer (score 1):

Because the class you are using for POST request is `VerifyLoginDto` and the response type of this POST request is `VerifyLoginRespDto`.

The `VerifyLoginRespDto` must have property `accessToken` which is mapped to `access_token`.

**NOTE : Please DON'T USE property name like this `private String access_token;`. You should follow `camel case` , because java and Spring follow this very sensitively. All the bean will be created according to camel case only.**